# How to properly support 2-3 with ground nm-b cable from floor joists

Tags: electrical, wiring

I bought a house where the previous homeowner hung 2-3 with ground nm-b (cable) with metallic conduit hangers from wall studs below the floor joists.

It looks like the hangers are cutting through the protective sheathing.

Other than running conduit or armored cable are there proper hangers to anchor this cable on its way to a laundry room sub-panel?

Comment: A photo would be helpful.

Comment: Do you mean 2 or 3 cables, or a single cable with three 2 AWG conductors  and ground wire in it?

Answer (score 1):

Sound like you need to replace the pipe supports with J-hooks and either zip-ties or Velcro straps.

Here is an example of a [J-hook](https://www.zoro.com/caddy-j-hook-wall-mount-cat12/i/G2382956/?gdffi=047ada998cf641fa93e55ae8579df863&gdfms=35E00DC7385D42EF9108A2AB21D67B4E&gclid=CjwKEAjwuuy4BRCvs43g9fX9mz4SJACiYydP0g4E3Hsg4y7fL58NFtt2-8Hl1ckEZVqVkXqEnWGvoRoC71zw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds).

Notice the rounded edges to prevent cable sheath damage. These supports are required for structured cabling (Cat5) bundles to prevent wire distortion and damage. But would also work well for your application.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The proper way is electrical staples and no more than 2 ea cables under a staple. The insulation is not supposed to be broken. [Here are search results](https://www.google.com/search?q=romex%20staples&espv=2&biw=1920&bih=979&tbm=isch&imgil=sjn7QmwhuBmcQM%253A%253BV0TYgprgPlYqcM%253Bhttps%25253A%25252F%25252Fstore.aihalaska.com%25252Findex.php%25253Fmain_page%2525253Dindex%25252526cPath%2525253D5_509_50990&source=iu&pf=m&fir=sjn7QmwhuBmcQM%253A%252CV0TYgprgPlYqcM%252C_&usg=__hag73rzb17UuQHaTbPIUDPbOWJ0%3D&ved=0ahUKEwilid605qbJAhUJVYgKHTv4ByQQyjcIWw&ei=nyhTVuW9DYmqoQS78J-gAg#imgrc=sjn7QmwhuBmcQM%3A&usg=__hag73rzb17UuQHaTbPIUDPbOWJ0%3D) showing several different types.

The most common here in the US is the square with a small flat across the back as they are the quickest and cheapest.

Comment: Hmmm, can you get staples that fit #2-3 NM? I thought the OP meant 12/3 also but then he says it terminates in a sub-panel. I think he really means 2/3 NM cable.

Comment: Guess I was thinking 12-3 + for the catch